# Issues with Cupertino Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

I am trying to create a custom CupertinoNavigationBar but I keep getting errors related to ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget. Can someone tell me what I need to implement to fix this? The error message I am getting is:

> Missing concrete implementation of 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget.shouldFullyObstruct'. Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract.

Here is the class for my CupertinoNavigationBar:

```dart
class CupertinoTopBar extends StatelessWidget
    implements ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget {
        Size preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoNavigationBar(
      leading: Text('AUC_CS'),
      backgroundColor: CupertinoTheme.of(context).primaryColor,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error messages or logs?

Comment: @0x4b50 Yes, I have added to the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement [`ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget-class.html) you have to implement the following methods:

```dart
  @override
  // TODO: implement preferredSize
  Size get preferredSize => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  bool shouldFullyObstruct(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement shouldFullyObstruct
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
```